# django mutiupload not working

Tags: python, django

what im trying to do is upload multiply files at once 
the code is pretty old and wondering if any one can help or is there a better way on doing this

here is my code 
model.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=only_filename)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.docfile.name

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('upload-delete', )
```

forms.py

```
class MyUploadForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = MultiFileField(max_num=3, min_num=1, max_file_size=1024*1024*5)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        super(MyUploadForm, self).save(commit=commit)

        for each in self.cleaned_data['docfile']:
            att = Attachment(parent=self.instance, file=each)
            att.save()

        return self.instance
```

and view.py

```
@login_required
def list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.user = request.user
            newdoc.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('multiupload.views.list'))
    else:
        form = MyUploadForm() # A empty, unbound form

    documents = Document.objects.all

    return render_to_response(
        'sample/index.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's not a correct way...

Don't override save in forms.py and put create each new object in views after valid() like...

```
def list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = form.cleaned_data['docfile']
            for file_obj in request.FILES.getlist('docfile'):
                Document.objects.create(docfile=file_obj)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('multiupload.views.list'))
```

Comment: so how would i go by using newdoc.user = request.user  cause when i do i get "'list' object has no attribute 'user'" and thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you use pl-upload jQuery plugin, I personally use this plugin and this is pretty easy and uploading is very fast.

Here are some of example :

[Read a blog here](http://django-posts.blogspot.in/2014/11/ajax-based-plupload-using-django.html)

[Code example you look here](https://github.com/vitalyvolkov/plupload-django-example)